# how to count number of characters in a file in C#?

Tags: c#

I tried

```
    string str1 = File.ReadAllText("D:\\this.txt");
    str1.Length;
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\this.txt");
    fileBytes.Length;
```

gone thru [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214772/counting-number-of-characters-in-a-file-c-sharp)
but each time same problem arises, it counts carriage return and new line also
like in my file data is

```
123
456
7
```

it is showing '11' but output should be '7'
help needed
EDIT:  i want to count every element which have ASCII greater than or equal to 32

Comment: Trim and replace the \n and \n\r with string.empty before you count.

Comment: Do you want files with similar content, but different formatting, to have the same "length"?

Comment: This approach (coupled with the answers below) is fine if your file is guaranteed to be small. If you potentially have to process very large files you should look at reading a line at a time.

Comment: How do you want to count combining characters? Do you want a count of what is visually displayed for reading or raw characters (except for carriage return / new line)?

Comment: Possible linq solution: `var a = (from ch in str1 where ch != '\r' && ch != '\n' select ch).Count();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could load all lines, then add all the lengths of each line together using linq:

```
var numberOfCharacters = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\this.txt").Sum(s => s.Length);
```

**Alternative**

Doesn't count whitespace except space or controls chars. Requirements are fuzzy, but should put you on right track.

```
 var numberOfCharacters = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\this.txt").
    Count(c => c==" " ||
    (!Char.IsControl(c) &&
     !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

Comment: This will count the whitespaces as characters as well. I have a feeling the op wants to count everything but tabs, spaces and newlines.

Comment: Well I don't code to specifications based on feelings. This works for the given example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to attack you or your answer. I was simply pointing out something that might be of importance for future readers and perhaps even the op.

Comment: The question says "it counts carriage return and new line". Looks like part of the spec to me.

Comment: @DanielKelley Yes that is part of the spec. But no mention of white space. Was that your downvote?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I'm not offended. You make a good point, it does count white space. But it's a guess either way whether that in the spec. I'm working TDD style, I do just enough to make it work.

Comment: @weston Good point - I was clearly reading more into it than was actually there.

Comment: white spaces should be included
in short anything with ASCII greater than or equal to 32 (spaceASCII) should be counted not anything below it

Comment: @Ritwik oh, so don't count tab (ASCII 9)?

Comment: i dont think in my case it should be considered (for counting)

Answer (score 1):

Well character count will always (and should always) count non-visible characters because they *are* still characters. You can look on the MSDN for [what qualifies as a whitespace character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9a023cx.aspx) and use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I would like to make note that, although the other responses will work, they're neglecting the fact that carriage return and line-feed are not the only non-visible whitespace characters you will encounter. And different OS's will handle "Enter" or "Return" differently. Some with just `\n` and others with '\r\n'.